# PATCH_SUPEE-9767 Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, ce-1.9.2.2, supee-9767

I am trying to install Patch 9767 but using following command

```
~$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh
```

But i got below error and patch is not install

```
: not found-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh: 7: PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh: 
PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh: 10: local: not in a function
```

So i am trying to install patch using php file using following code

```
$result = shell_exec('sh PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh');
```

but i got below error

```
ERROR: "/app/etc/" must exist for proper tool work.
```

Comment: have you uploaded patch file on then magento setup root folder?

Comment: Yes PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh file is on magento root folder

Comment: check your root path sh file permission.

its need 777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following command before.

> sudo chmod +x sh PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.9.3.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-09-56.sh

And after use

./ patch file name.